# Printing custom url with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, printing, window

I'm trying to print another page on my domain by passing window.open the url, and using window.focus, window.print to print. However, the print preview shows only an empty page. I'm guessing I have to wait until the page is loaded,  but I'm not sure exactly how to do this. Here's the code:

```
var newWin=window.open('http://mydomain.com');
newWin.focus(); 
newWin.print(); 
newWin.close();
```

I've tried stuff like

```
newWin.onload() {
    newWin.print();
});
```

to no avail.

Edit 1:

```
var newWin=window.open('http://localhost:76');
newWin.focus(); 
newWin.onload = newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

Same problem persists

Edit 2:

```
var newWin=window.open('http://localhost:76');
newWin.focus(); 
newWin.body.onload = newWin.print();
```

Adding newWin.close() here causes the print function to 
bug out and only print the
title of the page. Otherwise, the page is printing properly with this

Edit 3:

```
function printWin(newWin) {
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}

var newWin = window.open('http://localhost:76');
newWin.focus();
newWin.body.onload = printWin(newWin);
```

This causes the print to happen prematurely like before, previewing an empty page. wtf :(

Comment: could you check if the onload event runs by placing an alert within please?

Comment: Checked, and edited code in OP. The alert was getting called

Comment: var newWin=window.open('http://localhost:76');
    newWin.printme = function() { this.print(); }
    newWin.printme();
    newWin.close();

Comment: hmm this is weird, could you try the window.print() method in your own window please, just to see if first of all this is working?

Comment: Check OP, it's printing the popup window, but not working with newWin.close();

Answer (score 2):

Open the popup. Then check if the popup is ready. When it's ready, inject a javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var popup = window.open("b.htm");
    var body;
    function check() {
        body = popup.document.getElementsByTagName("body");
        if (body[0] == null) {
            setTimeout(check, 50);
        } else {
            var n = popup.document.createElement("script");
            n.src = "printandclose.js";
            body.appendChild(n);
        }
    }
    check();

</script>
```

printandclose.js

```
window.print();
window.open("", "_self");
window.close();
```

Let me know if it works. If you don't add `window.open("", "_self");` a alert will popup telling the user that the window is about to close.

Comment: I only need access to pages within my domain.  Google is just a placeholder...but the problem still exists for pages within my domain. I'll edit the OP, thanks :)

Comment: Ideally nothing will need to be placed in the child page getting opened. There are hundreds of child pages which might get opened, so it would be nice to not have to put code in each one :). Is there any way I can call a body onload for the child page from the parent page maybe?

Comment: Actually, the solution was simpler than we thought. Check edit 2. Only problem now is getting the window to close after print.

Comment: I tried your solution, and tried modifying a bit (edit 3) ... both didn't work :(. In your edit 2, the code within the function doesn't get executed. In my edit 3, the print happens prematurely like before. Grr..

Comment: Thanks user1330271, I'll try this and get back to you